# How to get ansible tower hostname

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Any way to retrieve the ansible tower hostname from where i ssh/run my job?

Aka ; from a ansible fact variable ..?

I need to know the ansible tower hostname when i run a job from inventory hostname

Thanks
Dominic

Comment: Have you try to set the gather_facts to true and get something like ansible.hostname from there?

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch that information from "execution_node" variable.

Comment: it wont show you in facts. Assuming if you are running it from Tower, you can debug this variable to get that information. Take a look at this to get a basic overview of what variables does ansible tower set during run time:: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/3.2.1/html/towerapi/project_update.html

Comment: Ok now I see. Get this variable from api rest request! Thanks